# Extract substring after varying condition

Tags: r, string, substring, stringr

this is my first post on this site. I am currently struggeling to extract a substring out of multiple strings based on a varying condition. The strings I am working are from a FASTA file and look like this:

```
strings <- c("gi|0|gb|MK004980| Bat astrovirus isolate DXRA19 RNA-dependent RNA polymerase gene, partial cds. [DXRA19 (BVI10455)]",
             "gi|225381010|gb|FJ571114| Bat astrovirus Tm/Guangxi/LD61/2007 RNA-dependent RNA polymerase (pol) gene, partial cds. [Tm/Guangxi/LD61/2007 (BVI03388)]")
```

My goal is now to remove the first part of the string (the part with "X|Y|Z|A|") and extract only the name of the specific sequence so it should look like this:

```
strings_final <- c("Bat astrovirus isolate DXRA19 RNA-dependent RNA polymerase gene, partial cds. [DXRA19 (BVI10455)]",
             "Bat astrovirus Tm/Guangxi/LD61/2007 RNA-dependent RNA polymerase (pol) gene, partial cds. [Tm/Guangxi/LD61/2007 (BVI03388)]")
```

As you see the first part to be removed varies in legth, with the only consistent part being the four "|" as well as the "gi" and "gb". I know that I can use this pattern to remove this and extract only the part after it. However, I am currently struggeling to code this in R as I dont know which expression to use to fit this pattern in e.g., the stringr::str_extract() function.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

I tried using the stringr::str_extract() function but I dont know which pattern I should put in to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
sub(".*\\| *", "", strings)
# [1] "Bat astrovirus isolate DXRA19 RNA-dependent RNA polymerase gene, partial cds. [DXRA19 (BVI10455)]"                          
# [2] "Bat astrovirus Tm/Guangxi/LD61/2007 RNA-dependent RNA polymerase (pol) gene, partial cds. [Tm/Guangxi/LD61/2007 (BVI03388)]"
```

Regex:

- `.*` *anything* (or nothing)
- `\\|` literal pipe symbol, need to escape it since otherwise it is a regex operator
- `*` zero or more spaces

This effectively removes up to the *last* pipe-symbol found and any blank space (if any) immediately after it. `sub` differs from `gsub` in that `sub` only makes one such substitution and quits, and in this case that's all that we need.

Alternative (though not my preferred): one can also use `read.table` assuming that all strings have the same number of `|`-symbols:

```r
trimws(read.table(text = strings, sep = "|")[,5])
# [1] "Bat astrovirus isolate DXRA19 RNA-dependent RNA polymerase gene, partial cds. [DXRA19 (BVI10455)]"                          
# [2] "Bat astrovirus Tm/Guangxi/LD61/2007 RNA-dependent RNA polymerase (pol) gene, partial cds. [Tm/Guangxi/LD61/2007 (BVI03388)]"
```

where we need `trimws` to remove the space between `|` and `Bat`.